# my C- disc is Dirty and I cant find a way to fix it

Tags: windows-11, chkdsk

The problem suddenly started to appear when I got back from my 3 week holiday without using my computer. Suddenly everytime I turn on/wake from sleep/restart my computer windows runs chkdsk. And it turns out my disk i "dirty" somehow

I've read that you should schedule a chkdsk (because my c disc is my windows disk), but when I restart my computer the chkdsk runs, but I get no sign of progress and the whole thing is over within 5 seconds, I get into windows and by using `fsutil dirty query c:` it shows that my C drive is still dirty.

What do I do? Its pretty tiring that every reebot triggers chkdsk, without it helping.

Notice: everything on my computer works as expected, the only difference is that chkdsk runs everytime i boot

Update: after downloading new firmware update for my drive the chkdsk no longer runs on boot, but drive is still dirty.

Comment: Does "Event Viewer" (eventvwr.msc) mention anything regarding NTFS _or_ disk errors?

Comment: im going on windows logs -> system and i have a couple : The driver detected a controller error on \Device\RaidPort1 AND  Volume C: (\Device\HarddiskVolume3) needs to be taken offline to perform a Full Chkdsk.  Please run "CHKDSK /F" locally via the command line, or run "REPAIR-VOLUME <drive:>" locally or remotely via PowerShell.

Comment: Hey @KimVu, I'm wondering, how did you solve this in the end? I saw that you removed the dirty bit with chkdsk from cmd in recovery, but did the dirty bit ever come back?

Comment: I haven't ran chkdsk since the problem was fixed, so I think the dirty bit is still gone. No more automatically running chkdsk when booting my computer which was the main issue, so I haven't been bothered to check if the bit is still "clean". I'll doublecheck for you later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the chkdsk never managed to complete during bootup, so I did an advanced startup and with command line: I wrote `chkdsk C: /f /r` then rebooted to check if the disk was still dirty, and it was not.   ....

Comment: well my case is the same as yours. Need to go to advanced start up  by clicking the `restart button + shift`, then choose `Troubleshoot -> Advanced Options - Command Prompt`. Run command `chkdsk C: /f /r`. If there are any questions about `unmount disk` and `do check after system restart` just answer Yes. For me it takes about 19 min with 400GB of data in PCIE SSD gen 4x4 with Ryzen 5 7650HS

Answer (score 3):

A ["dirty volume"](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-performance/what-does-volume-dirty-mean-after-running-check/5f03cefa-0c1b-48aa-9d99-101458914c26) not only indicates possible **disk** issues, it may also be an issue created by some software writing to the disk *during or after Windows OS shut down.*

> "The dirty bit is set for two main causes - a software problem such as your improper shutdown, or a more serious hardware problem that can indicate a failing drive. "

1. Make a *complete disk image*, preferably using an external USB drive with rescue media, such as created by [Macrium Reflect](https://blog.macrium.com/the-macrium-rescue-environment-cca57a4ebc61), by [AOMEI Backupper](https://www.ubackup.com/bootable-rescue-media-creator.html), or other third-party software. This avoids *writing* to the existing drive, which can cause further damage. An image saves all your data, applications and the operating system, should things fail badly.
2. Check the drive [S.M.A.R.T. data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis,_and_Reporting_Technology) with a tool such as free [HWiNFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Monitoring,_Analysis,_and_Reporting_Technology):

   [image: HWiNFO S.M.A.R.T. data]
3. See if anything is writing to the disk during or after shutdown.

   a. If the machine dual-boots, or is available over LAN, and the drive is mounted with *write* permission, Windows will see changes in the disk as making it "dirty". This is *not* damage to the disk, but a warning that it was used outside of Windows. This is particularly important if Fast Boot or Hibernation is enabled, as Windows expects the serialized state of the machine stored on the drive to be untouched.

   b. Check the Windows Event Logs immediately after shutdown and reboot for a program or service that did not shut down gracefully. A tool such as Nirsoft's [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html) lets you examine all the myriad of logs simultaneously.
   c. Try a *forced* shutdown and then reboot, to see if that avoided the *dirty volume* issue. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type `shutdown /s /t 0` and the machine will shut **immediately**, stopping any program still running. If, after reboot, the drive is OK, then that indicates some app or service is not ending properly.
4. Finally, if it seems the disk is failing, try some of [these tools](https://www.lifewire.com/free-hard-drive-testing-programs-2626183) for more info. They might cause further damage, but in step 1, you made a backup, so no problem.

Comment: everything is green on S.M.A.R.T data with HWiNFO

Comment: Then look for something writing to the drive when it shouldn't be. On a dual bot machine, if I forcefully mount my C: drive writable with Ubuntu while Windows is hibernated, on waking up, the machine reboots, rather than resumes from hibernation, since it "knows" something touched the disk where hiberfil.sys is stored -- this is a security measure to help prevent a malefactor from substituting a bad hiberfil.

Comment: in the event viewer I have "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\RaidPort1." and Volume C: (\Device\HarddiskVolume3) needs to be taken offline to perform a Full Chkdsk. Could these be the problem?

Comment: The driver detected a controller error on .....    The drive controller could have  a problem, but then disk replacement is still required as we both have noted to you,

Answer (score 1):

Back up the disk and see if you can do a complete backup.

Get the disk manufacturer's drive diagnostics app and test the drive.

Then either:

(1) Replace the drive (most likely thing to do here) and install Windows.

Or, if you have confidence in the drive (does not seem likely)

(2) Format the drive and install Windows.

Comment: replacing would be a real shame... the disk is only 3months old and I haven't really been installing anything on it.

Comment: Decent software today will not normally cause a dirty disk, so more likely it is an early hardware issue.